# java substring can run on out of range index?

Tags: java, string

```
public class Main {


    public static String reverseWords(String s) {
        StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder();
        int j = s.length();
        for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                j = i;
            } else if (i == 0 || s.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
                if (reversed.length() != 0) {
                    reversed.append(' ');
                }
                reversed.append(s.substring(i, j));
            }
        }
        return reversed.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "sky is blue";
        String retStr = reverseWords(str);
        System.out.println(retStr);

    }
}
```

This is a proven runnable and corect doe. IT reverse sentence's words order.

But this line.

```
 reversed.append(s.substring(i, j));
```

It will be called at first time as s.substring(7,11) and s is "sky is blue".
so you can see index 7 is 'b' but index 11 is after 'e' .

In c++ i know this mus cause issue. But why in Java, it is fine? so confused.
I checked java document and it says substring() takes start and end index.
I don't know now.

need help
thanks

Comment: "_java substring can run on out of range index?_" No, it can't.

Answer (score 1):

The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1.

Comment: Since this is a direct quote from the docs, you should put a link to them [like this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)).